# Getting .p4ignore to work out of the box (like a .gitignore)

Tags: perforce

I have committed a .p4ignore to the root of my working directory, and tried it out, it did not ignore any file.

So now, I have understood that if I want .p4ignore to be taken into account, I have to set up the following environment variable :

```
p4 set P4IGNORE=.p4ignore
```

This is a bit cumbersome to type every time I switch projects. Is there a way to have the feature working out of the box by committing both a P4CONFIG file like `.p4settings` and a `.p4ignore` ?

I have read [P4CONFIG documentation](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/P4CONFIG.html) but this is not crystal clear. P4CONFIG has the interesting property to be able to be found anywhere in the directory tree (like a .gitignore)

If I do a 
   `p4 set P4CONFIG=.p4settings`

and put inside .p4settings

```
P4IGNORE=.p4ignore
```

It seems to be somewhat working, but I want to know if this is the correct approach or if something easier is possible to set up ?

Comment: You should be able to set `P4IGNORE=.p4ignore` in an environment variable, and then it will be honored across all clients.

Comment: I routinely put P4IGNORE setting in my P4CONFIG. There is nothing wrong with this approach. The big question is: do you want to have the same P4IGNORE settings for every workspace on your workstation, or do different workspaces have different settings? P4CONFIG is ideal for setting per-workspace configuration, while global P4IGNORE setting is simpler if you end up using the same settings for every workspace.

Comment: Maybe I should have mentioned it, but I actually have different .gitignore in different workspace, they contain some generic stuff like *.o, but also some relative path for some generated files that are very workspace specific. Hence the juggling of files.

Comment: I find this quite lacking overall. If I want to share my `.p4ignore` file with my colleagues, I `p4 add` it to the project but my colleagues must still set `P4IGNORE` the same way I do. I can, of course, do what @XavierT. proposes, i.e. put `P4IGNORE=.p4ignore` into `.p4settings` and `p4 add .p4settings`, but that just shifts the problem because for it to be effective, my colleagues must have `P4CONFIG` set the same way as myself. I have yet to find a solution that works implicitly like `.gitignore`.

Comment: @sferencik: I agree it seems overly complex for no good reason.

Comment: Those are good points. I know that P4IGNORE has been substantially improved in recent versions; have you checked the newest releases to see if any of these problems have been addressed?